# Testing BizTalk by picking up XML from file locations

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a simple orchestration which subscribes to a message, changes a status field in the message header then send back to the message box.

To test this I have hooked it up to a file location to accept an incoming XML message (as the system which will produce the message is not yet complete) and would then want the new message with the changed header sent to a new file location.

I can see the XML file disappearing as it is picked up, but I'm not clear on how to then output that to a new XML file.  There are no maps involved so I'm unsure how to configure a send port to pick up from the message box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a filter on send port based on some promoted properties of the message.

some example or filters: BTS.MessageType = "MessageType"

Once you add a filter in send port It will subscribe from the message box.